# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (current_item.quantity += 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
        current_item.quantity += 1
    else
        current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end
```

I got an error (3rd) line, it says **undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
I have no idea what's wrong :|
**

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord

has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy


def add_product(product_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
  if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
  else
    current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
  end
  current_item
end

**And my line_controller**

def create
  product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @line_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart, notice: 'Line item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @line_item }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def change
  add_column :line_items, :quantity, :integer, default: 1
end
```

Comment: "I have no idea what's wrong" - the error tells you. `current_item.quantity` is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `current_item.quantity += 1`
 => `current_item.increment(:quantity)` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `byebug` for make sure that `quantity` present.
I can suggest that solution

```
current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)

if current_item.present?
  current_item.quantity += 1 unless current_item.quantity.nil?
else
  current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
end
current_item
```

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you want to check with the quantity? if it is bigger than 1? I am not sure if your operator works that way because A +=B does A = A + B. However, Since you get a nil class error the current_item seems to be nil. Please make sure that the current_item is found by rails. Or the quantity is nil. I saw that @Iceman already answered your question.

Pass product_id into params and make sure that you have a find_by(:product_id) in your controller. When you get the current_item and it is not nil all you need to do is check if quantity is nil. If some quantities are nil you might escape the error with and if loop. e,g. if nil do nothing else etc.